# Центровка карты по местоположению

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Необходимо определить координаты местоположения и отобразить карту согласно определенному местоположению. Если местоположение определить не удается, то центр карты установить на Москве.

Проблема в том, что `ymaps.geolocation.get` работает асинхронно и не получается создать карту с координатами местоположения.

Вкратце что я хочу сделать:

1. Создаем переменную текущих координат местоположения: `var current_coords = null;`
2. Определяем координаты местоположения с помощью `ymaps.geolocation.get`, если координаты не определены, то возвращаем координаты Москвы
3. Присваиваем переменной `current_coords` полученные на шаге 2 координаты
4. Создаем и отображаем карту: `var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {center: current_coords, zoom: 6});`
5. Добавляем на карту точки, зоны в виде многоугольников и т.д.

Получается, что надо ожидать, пока шаг 2 не отработает, а только затем выполнять шаги 3-5. Не могу понять, как это можно реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

В этом примере показано как обрабатывать получение местоположения https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocated_map

Comment: Это понятно, но тогда в ветке `function (res){}` и `function (err){}` я буду описывать одно и то же - шаги 4-5

Comment: Ну тогда вынесите их в функцию) Если вы хотите сделать, чтобы только после появления геолокации появилась карта, тогда нужно сделать функцию создания карты и передавать в неё координаты в зависимости от результатов геолокации. Кстати у геолокации есть опция таймаута, к примеру, если хотите ждать ответа строго определённое время https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geolocation-docpage/#method_detail__get-param-options

Comment: Делать функцию тоже не вариант - придется одну и ту же функцию писать в двух ветках. Можно же как-то использовать промисы и Promise.all?

Comment: Функция одна и таже, значения то разные. Создать карту с этими координатами или создать карту с другими координатами. Вы можете создать карту до и потом установить ей новый центр, когда придет геолокация, но это будет отступление от той логики, которую вы описали.

Comment: Устанавливать новый центр карты не вариант, нужно сразу отображать карту в нужной геолокации. Вроде получилось сделать (см. выше)

Comment: Усложнили код на пустом месте) Если работаете со стандартным coordorder то координаты задайте в другом порядке.

Comment: Можете предложить свой вариант (на примере) :)

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать таким образом:

```js
var current_coords = null; // координаты текущего местоположения

ymaps.vow.Promise.all([getGeolocation()]).then(function(res){
  myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
   center: res[0],
   zoom: 6
  });
});

/* Определение координат местоположения */
function getGeolocation(){
 var сoordinates_promise = ymaps.geolocation.get({
  provider: 'yandex',
  mapStateAutoApply: true
 }).then(
  function(res){
   return res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
  }
 ).catch(function (err){
  console.log('Ошибка определения местоположения');
  return [37.61691485505143, 55.7517318022522];
 });
 return сoordinates_promise;
}
```